# Create template/image of AWS servers, frameworks and configs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-ebs

I have the following setup on AWS for a web application

- Elastic Bean Stalk java server
- Several S3 buckets each for a different purpose
- Several Cloudfront distributions
- Route53 configurations
- Lambda functions
- Code deploy configuration

Could you advise on an approach to create a template/image of the above. I would like to be able to easily create and deploy the above with the same configurations without the need to setup from scratch

Comment: You can read the document AWS Best Practices that you can download from here https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Cloud_Best_Practices.pdf

Comment: @nacho I can't see an example in the document you shared. Can you share a step-by-step guide on how to implement such, if you have one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the s3 bucket, ec2 server, cloudfront, route 53 configurations you can create one single cloudformation template.

For the lambda functions create a separate cloudformation template.

Similar for the code deploy config.

Comment: any references on how to create the template you mentioned above?